# Spark read csv: Using "sep" option for tab but everything comes up in one column

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to read a tab-delimited file in spark (scala) like so:

```
spark.read.option("sep", '\t').csv(location)
```

But the schema comes out like this:

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)


scala> df.show
+------+
|   _c0|
+------+
|3  1   .1|
|3  2   .2|
|3  4   .3|
|2  1   .4|
|2  3   .5|
+------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update: I think this is different from the general question of how to read a TSV file in spark because it's not obvious that passing a character argument for the delimiter instead of a String should break anything--in fact when I stepped into the code it says it's just calling .toString on the value parameter, which *should* make passing '\t' equivalent to passing "\t". As it is I still don't know what's going wrong, but I do know that switching to "\t" fixed it. Hopefully someone who can explain the difference can chime in at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Putting tab as a string instead of a character fixed it:

```
scala> val df = spark.read.option("sep", "\t").csv(location)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: string, _c1: string ... 1 more field]
```